# Porque no me sincroniza los datos firebase

Tags: java, firebase

Tengo un problema y es que no se me sincronizan los datos,el fichero compila , segui este tutorial https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/admin/save-data?hl=es-419 y compila correctamente pero no se me cambian los datos , desde android lo consegui.

Segui este tutorial https://firebase.google.com/docs/admin/setup?hl=es-419

¿Alguna idea?

```
    FileInputStream serviceAccount = new FileInputStream("keyok.json");

FirebaseOptions options = new FirebaseOptions.Builder()
.setCredentials(GoogleCredentials.fromStream(serviceAccount))
.setDatabaseUrl("https://name.com/")
.build();

   FirebaseApp.initializeApp(options);


DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();

DatabaseReference usersRef = ref.child("users");

Map<String, User> users = new HashMap<>();
users.put("alanisawesome", new User("June 23, 1912", "Alan Turing"));
users.put("gracehop", new User("December 9, 1906", "Grace Hopper"));

usersRef.setValueAsync(users);
```

Answer (score 0):

Usa lo siguiente para actualizar los datos

```
usersRef.updateChildren(users);
```